# Clarify instructions for learnyounode exercise 6 - MAKE IT MODULAR

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a hard time following along with the provided instructions. I'm unclear on references made to which file is the module, and which file is the "original program file," which is "your program" and similar.

I can find solutions to this exercise, and I vaguely understand how/why they are solutions, but when I try to build from scratch I have a hard time following along with the provided instructions. I'm unclear on references made to which file is the module, and which file is the "original program file."

My question is: will someone please clarify these instructions for me? Secondly, I'd like to know if it is possible to solve this problem with all of the module import statements in one file -- maybe the "main.js" file? (As opposed to having the fs and path imports within the MAKE IT MODULAR module.) Also, is it possible to console.log from the module file, so that in the main.js file you only have to call the module function with parameters in order to log the filtered results?

I can see scope rules requiring file-specific imports, but am interested to learn what is required or possible.

This lesson begins by referencing the solution to the previous exercise, which is a js file which imports fs and path and defines a function which does a file sort by file extension within a specified directory. The directory name and file extension string are taken as arguments.

MAKE IT MODULAR asks to expand upon the previous answer by putting the sort function into a module and using that module to deliver the same sort results.

Here is my solution to the previous exercise. I understand that I will have to move the "." concat to another function per this exercise's requirements. I also understand I could have used a .forEach method, as was used in the official solution, included below.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var fileType = "." + process.argv[3]

fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function (err, list) {
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (path.extname(list[i]) === fileType) {
      console.log(list[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Official:

```
var folder = process.argv[2]
var ext = '.' + process.argv[3]

fs.readdir(folder, function (err, files) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  files.forEach(function (file) {
    if (path.extname(file) === ext) {
      console.log(file)
    }
  })
})
```

Here is the exercise:

> This problem is the same as the previous but introduces the concept of modules. You will need to create two files to solve this.
>
> Create a program that prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by the extension of the files. The first argument is the directory name and the second argument is the extension filter. Print the list of files (one file per line) to the console. You must use asynchronous I/O.

This "program" is the file from the previous exercise, with two arguments, correct?

> You must write a module file to do most of the work. The module must export a single function that takes three arguments: the directory name, the filename extension string and a callback function, in that order. The filename extension argument must be the same as what was passed to your program. Don't turn it into a RegExp or prefix with "." or do anything except pass it to your module where you can do what you need to make your filter work.

This "module file" is the same as referenced in the previous paragraph ("program"), correct? The module file exports the function, which is the file which is imported to something like main.js?

> The filename extension argument must be the same as what was passed to your program.

But if the "original program" is the one with the function with two arguments how can the same file be the one with the function with three arguments? And a reference to "that was passed to your program" makes it sound like the "other" file is the program file?

> The callback function must be called using the idiomatic node(err, data) convention. This convention stipulates that unless there's an error, the first argument passed to the callback will be null, and the second will be your data. In this exercise, the data will be your filtered list of files, as an Array. If you receive an error, e.g. from your call to fs.readdir(), the callback must be called with the error, and only the error, as the first argument.

My understanding is that both files have callback functions, so I think I'll have to error handle both files.

> You must not print directly to the console from your module file, only from your original program.
>
> In the case of an error bubbling up to your original program file, simply check for it and print an informative message to the console.

OK, now I'm really confused... The "original program" IS the "module file", isn't it? As in the "module file" is the one that exports, and is then imported into something like main.js, or a main "program" file, but not the "Original" program, the one that was created in the previous exercise?

And lastly:

> These four things are the contract that your module must follow.
>
> 1. Export a single function that takes exactly the arguments described.
> 2. Call the callback exactly once with an error or some data as described.
> 3. Don't change anything else, like global variables or stdout.
> 4. Handle all the errors that may occur and pass them to the callback.
>
> The benefit of having a contract is that your module can be used by anyone who expects this contract. So your module could be used by anyone else who does learnyounode, or the verifier, and just work.

I expect the "module" file to be the "original program" file, with a function with 2 arguments exported, which is imported to a "main program" file with a function with 3 arguments, which prints to the console.

Please help me reconcile the terminology I have in my mental model with the terminology specified in the wording of this lesson. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This "program" is the file from the previous exercise, with two arguments, correct?

Yes, you can keep the file from the previous exercise, but edit it. It's still a program that will take two command line arguments, yes. Let's call this file `main.js`.

> This "module file" is the same as referenced in the previous paragraph ("program"), correct?

No. It's a new, separate file. Let's call it `filesHelper.js`. It's a module that will be imported by the main module ("the program").

The new file will contain much of the code that the program from the previous exercise did contain, yes. You should move it from the `main.js` into the `filesHelper.js`, inside that function that the module will export.

> The module file exports the function, which is the file which is imported to something like main.js?

Yes. The `filesHelper.js` module file will declare and export the function, the `main.js` file will import and call the function. So the code you previously had will now be distributed to the files as following:

```
// main.js
… // require the filesHelper

… process.argv[2], process.argv[3] … // a function call with a callback
  … // error handling
  for (… i = 0; i < ….length; i++) { // don't forget to declare the index variable
    console.log(list[i]);
  }
});
```

```
// filesHelper.js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

… // a function declaration with three parameters
  fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function (err, list) {
    … // error handling (delegate to the callback)
    …
    for (… i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (path.extname(list[i]) === fileType) {
        … // build the result array
      }
    }
    … // call the callback with the result
  });

… // export the function
```

Fill in the blanks :-)

> I'd like to know if it is possible to solve this problem with all of the module import statements in one file -- maybe the `main.js` file? (As opposed to having the `fs` and `path` imports within the `filesHelper.js` module.)

Yes, it's kinda possible, but it becomes absolutely unwieldy quickly. This is called "dependency injection", and you'd do it by giving your exported function 5 parameters not only 3, so that you can pass in the `fs` and `path` as extra arguments, and don't need to import them in the `filesHelper` any more.

The downside of this approach is that usual modules have more than just two imports, and having to pass dozens of them to every function from another module that you call is not maintainable. Also, your `main.js` would need to do *all* the imports, would need to know about the dependency details of every single module you wrote, and quickly become a god module.

So unless you actually have an application use case to use the same module multiple times with different dependencies, go for the normal declarative module import style.

> Is it possible to `console.log` from the module file, so that in the `main.js` file you only have to call the module function with parameters in order to log the filtered results?

Yes, it's possible for sure, but then it is no longer modular. The key point to modularity - apart from separation of concerns - is reusability.

Say you had another program, `main2`, that wanted to read all files with a certain extension from a certain directory, and then send their contents to a printer? You couldn't use the `filesHelper` for this if you had hardcoded the file name logging, but you can when you have a generic callback that is called with an array of results.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of research, and using Bergi's clarifying answer above, I've re-authored the question in a way that is perhaps more clear. I still don't think I would have been able to answer this within the context of the learnyounode tutorial, as this exercise introduces numerous concepts that weren't yet made clear in previous exercises, namely the division of logic between the callback placeholder variable name parameter in the module and the callback function definition within the actual parameter being specified as an argument when the function is called.

> This problem is the same as the previous but introduces the concept of modules. You will need to create two files to solve this: main.js and filesHelper.js.
>
> The high-level requirements of this lesson are the same as the previous: create a program that prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by the extension of the files. The first command line argument is the directory name and the second argument is the extension filter. Print the list of files (one file per line) to the console. You must use asynchronous I/O.
>
> You must write a fileHelper.js file to do most of the work. This file is the module file, and will contain much of the code from your solution to the previous exercise. The main difference is the module file must export a single function that takes three arguments: the directory name, the filename extension string and a callback function, in that order. The filename extension argument must be the same as what will be passed to your program via the command line arguments. Don't turn it into a RegExp or prefix with "." or do anything except pass it to your module where you can do what you need to make your filter function work.
>
> To define a single function export, you assign your function to the module.exports object within filesHelper.js, thus overwriting any value which is already there:

`module.exports = function (args) { /* ... */ }`

> Or you can use a named function and assign the name.

```
function filterFn(args) { /* ... */ }
module.exports = filterFn
```

> To use your new module within main.js, use the require() call in the same way that you require('fs') to load the fs module. The only difference is that for local modules must be prefixed with './'. So, if your file is named mymodule.js then:

`var mymodule = require('./mymodule.js')`

> The '.js' is optional here and you will often see it omitted. You now have the module.exports object in your module assigned to the mymodule variable within main.js. Since you are exporting a single function, mymodule is a function you can call!
>
> The third argument of the module (the callback function) will not have a function definition within the exported module function, but rather will have to be defined when provided as an actual parameter when the module function is being called from the main.js program file. (i.e. when calling the function from main.js, the 3 arguments will be file directory, file type filter, and "function (err, data) {/* … */}".) However, instructions for how errors or data should be handled by the callback function will be required within the exported function.
>
> In other words, the details of the "callback" argument/function are shared between the main function and the module function. Instructions within the exported function are responsible for returning either an error message, or the filtered list of files by specifying how callback will be called, either with only one argument in case of an error (callback(err)), or with the first argument null and the second containing the filtered file list as an array (callback(null, list)), while the actual function definition is to be specified when entering actual arguments to the program via main.js.
>
> Example:

```
function bar (callback) {  
  foo(function (err, data) {  
    if (err)  
      return callback(err) // early return

    // ... no error, continue doing cool things with `data`  

    // all went well, call callback with `null` for the error argument  

      callback(null, data)
    })
  }
```

> Furthermore, the callback function, when defined as an actual parameter in main.js, must be called using the idiomatic node(err, data) convention, and in the case of an error bubbling up to your main.js file, simply check for it and print an informative message to the console.
>
> You must not print directly to the console from your module file, only from main.js.
>
> These four things are the contract that your module must follow.
>
> 1. Export a single function that takes exactly the arguments described.
> 2. Call the callback exactly once with either an error or some data as described.
> 3. Don't change anything else, like global variables or stdout.
> 4. Handle all the errors that may occur and pass them to the callback.
>
> The benefit of having a contract is that your module can be used by anyone who expects this contract. So your module could be used by anyone else who does learnyounode, or the verifier, and just work.

Here is my code which passed the tests:

```
//filesHelper.js
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')

module.exports = function (directory, filterString, callbackFunction) {
  fs.readdir(directory, function (err, list) {
    if (err) {
      return callbackFunction(err)
    } else {
      var filteredList = []
      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (path.extname(list[i]) === "." + filterString) {
          filteredList.push(list[i])
        }
      }
    }  
    callbackFunction(null, filteredList)
  })
}
```

...

```
//main.js
var myModule = require('./filesHelper.js')

var directory = process.argv[2]
var filterString = process.argv[3]

myModule(directory, filterString, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error: ', err)
  } else {
    for (const file of data) console.log(file)
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't forget to declare `filteredList` as a local variable (with `var`/`let`/`const`). Looks good otherwise :-) Although if you know about `array.forEach`, one might have expected you to use `array.filter` as well

Comment: Maybe the assignment would have been cleaner if it separated the refactoring with a generic helper function from placing the helper function in an extra module, as two distinct tasks.

Comment: Thanks! fixed. I first solved by printing the whole array to the console, but per instructions needed to print one file per line, and the for loop seemed clumsy for that, so decided on .forEach. I saw solutions with .filter, but as I'm struggling with callbacks in general, wanted to not introduce yet another callback method.

Comment: I'd consider `for (const file of data) console.log(file)` to be *less* clumsy than `forEach` :-P

Comment: Indeed it is! Nice, thanks. Was able to get rid of closing } and ). Edited. Now reading up on for in and for of...